# Change Stack Overflow theme to other than light and dark

Tags: discussion

I remember a few months ago, the website was giving the option to try different themes without going to `preferences`.

Is that feature gone now or can it be accessed from somewhere else on the site?

Comment: That was an april fools thing. It wasn't meant to last (unfortunately)

Comment: Man wish it becomes a permanent feature.